# pytest does not honor pytest.ini

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

```
 tree
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── inner
│       └── __init__.py
├── pytest.ini
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_app.py
```

pytest.init contents

```
[pytest]
markers =
    exception
```

test case

```
@pytest.mark.exception(socket.gaierror())
def test_two_equals_two():
    assert 2 == 2
```

running pytest -v results in

```
 PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.exception - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/mark.html
@pytest.mark.exception(socket.gaierror())
```

edit 1 - usage of parameterless pytest.mark.* decorators is also mentioned in the warning log even though being registered in pytest.ini

Comment: The issue in your code is related to how you're using the @pytest.mark.exception decorator with parameters. You should not pass a function call as a parameter in the decorator. Instead, you should just use the marker name without parentheses.

Comment: there is nothing technically wrong with that as I can get the parameter value via request.node.get_closest_marker(name='exception')

however https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html might be a better option

Comment: Depends on how you are running your tests - `pytest.ini` has to be in the root path, so if you run the tests from the `tests` folder, it may not be found. You may want to move it into the "tests" folder.

Comment: thanks @MrBeanBremen I do have `pytest.ini` in the root folder and I am running my tests from there

Comment: Strange. Do you have some other init file (`pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg`) that may be used instead of `pytest.ini`?